# netbeans application platform 8 remove undo redo button

Tags: netbeans, toolbar, platform

netbeans application platform 8 remove undo / redo button

how to remove the default saveall undo and redo buttons from the toolbar of a NetBeans Platform Application 8.

I found an article describing how to edit the --> Important Files / XML Layer /  / Toolbars

but i think that is only applicable for netbeans <= 6.9

How to remove those buttons on NetBeans Platform Application 8.

Answer (score 0):

Declare following layers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE filesystem PUBLIC '-//NetBeans//DTD Filesystem 1.2//EN' 'http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/filesystem-1_2.dtd'>
<filesystem>
    <folder name="Toolbars">
        <folder name="File_hidden"/>
        <folder name="Clipboard_hidden"/>
        <folder name="UndoRedo_hidden"/>
    </folder>
</filesystem>
```